# SKSpriteNode bouncing when it shouldn't

Tags: ios7, bounce, sprite-kit, restitution, skspritenode

I'm developing a 2D game with the new API Sprite Kit. The problem is that although setting the restitution of a sprite node to 0, it bounces a little bit. How can I totally disable the bouncing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the restitution on both the objects that will meet.

```
    self.world = [SKNode node];
    [self addChild:self.world];

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointZero toPoint:CGPointMake(500, 0)];
    self.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;

    self.ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
    self.ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
    self.ball.physicsBody.density = 100;
    self.ball.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
    self.ball.position = CGPointMake(200, 300);
    [self.world addChild:self.ball];
```

Comment: @DogCoffee Thanks, but that didn't completely solve the problem in my case. I can still see some "trembling" even though both ``restitution``s are set to zero. Similar is asked here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315250/skphysicsbody-with-restitution-0-still-bounces). Do you have any idea how to completely "disable" bouncing?

Answer (score 1):

I found scaling the mass down works!

```
self.ball.physicsbody.mass=0.2;
```

Use a small number like that and it will not bounce, you will have to scale your gravity and impulses accordingly as well. I found `0.2` to work best with a grav of `-20`.

For whatever reason, even at 0 restitution, the average size objects are heavy enough to bounce.